# Kotlin does not allow T::class.java as a paramterized class type given to a java method

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I am about to make a service of mine generic. However I fail to do so when trying to pass a generic Kotlin type `T` to a Java method that expects a class. Using normal types I'd do it like `MyClass::class.java`. For the generic type I do `T::class.java`. This however seems not to be valid.

```
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

Happening here `return mongoTemplate.aggregate(resolvedDocument, T::class.java).mappedResults[0]`

Service:

```
@Service
class DocumentAggregator<T: Output>(
    @Autowired
    private val mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate
) {
    fun <S: DocumentEntity>aggregate(document: S): T? {
        val resolvedDocument: TypedAggregation<DocumentEntity> = // logic

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(resolvedDocument, T::class.java).mappedResults[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only be possible if your class has a `Class<T>` or `KClass<T>` property in its constructor, so the class's T type can be passed. I don't use Spring, so I don't know the implications for your dependency injection.

Comment: Similar to Java in Kotlin there happens [Type Erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure), so at runtime the type of the type parameter is not known and can therefore not be used for situations where a specific class is expected.

Comment: Would it help if I would not add a "constraint" like `: Output` ? Or will it never work with parameterized types?

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding the `reified` keyword to the generic parameter, like this:

```
class DocumentAggregator<reified T: Output>
```

That ways the class will be present at runtime. Like when you added an additional `Class<T>` parameter, just with the nice Kotlin syntax sugar.

EDIT:
Regarding the comments the question would be if you need the generics on the class. What compiles (thanks to Willie for pointing out the mistake) would be:

```
class Output

class DocumentAggregator(
    private val mongoTemplate: Any?
) {
    inline fun <S, reified T: Output>aggregate(document: S): T? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot use reified on generic types parameters of classes

Comment: @WilliMentzel so there is no way? I have to write repetitive code then... eh?

Comment: @xetra11 Not sure what you mean, but `class DocumentAggregator<reified T>`will give you the error "Only type parameters of inline functions can be reified". See here: https://pl.kotl.in/an86gfog0